# R - Print values using for, while, and repeat loop

Tags: r

I am having trouble again with my code. Here is the question and what I have right now:

```
# 2. Draw a random sample of size n=20 from a uniform distribution in 0 and 1 using 
#    runif(20). Sequentially, print values using the following rules:
#       i. Print a value if it is less than 0.3 or more than 0.8, but skip it 
#          (don’t print the value) if it is in (0.1, 0.2],
#      ii. Skip the entire process if you find a value in [0.4,0.5].
#    Write three separate R codes using (a) for loop, (b) while loop 
#    and (c) repeat loop. 

# (a) for loop
n = runif(20)
for (val in n){
  if (val > 0.1 & val <= 0.2){
    next
  } else if (val < 0.3 | val > 0.8){
    print(val)
  } else if (val >= 0.4 & val <= 0.5){
    print(val)
    break
  }
}

# (b) while loop
n = 1
m = runif(20)
while(n < 20){
  if (m > 0.1 & m <= 0.2){
    next
  } else if (m < 0.3 | m > 0.8){
    print(m)
  } else if (m >= 0.4 & m <= 0.5){
    print(m)
    break
  }
  n = n + 1
}

# (c) repeat loop
n = 1
m = runif(20)
repeat{
  if (m > 0.1 & m <= 0.2){
    next
  } else if (m < 0.3 | m > 0.8){
    print(val)
  } else if (m >= 0.4 & m <= 0.5){
    print(m)
    break
  }
}
```

Part (a) for loop is working perfectly.

My only issue is (b) while loop and (c) repeat loop. He didn't do a good job in class or notes going over a while loop and repeat loop. Please help.

Comment: Can you, in your own words, describe what you're doing, what you're trying to do and what's going wrong?

Comment: (1) You are not indexing `m`. (2) In the `repeat` loop you are not even incrementing the index `n`. (3) When you do `next` the next instruction is the top of the loop so `n <- n + 1` is *not* executed.

Comment: @RuiBarradas How can I fix the while and repeat loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `m` that you created has a length of 20, so when you go to test it with something like `if (m > 0.1 & m <= 0.2)`, R only tests the first item in your object. To solve this, you'll need to index `m` with `n`, your loop counter. In other words, don't use `m` in your tests, but use `m[n]` instead. In all it should look like this:

```
n <- 1
m <- runif(20)
while(n < 20){
  if (m[n] > 0.1 & m[n] <= 0.2){
    next
  } else if (m[n] < 0.3 | m[n] > 0.8){
    print(m[n])
  } else if (m[n] >= 0.4 & m[n] <= 0.5){
    print(m[n])
    break
  }
  n <- n + 1
}
```

You should be able to use a similar approach for part c. (Also note that in part c you have `print(val)` at one point.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the exercise if for you to sort it out, but OK, I'll post a solution.

```
# (b) while loop
n = 1
m = runif(20)
while(n <= 20){
  if (m[n] > 0.1 & m[n] <= 0.2){
    n = n + 1
    next
  } else if (m[n] < 0.3 | m[n] > 0.8){
    print(m[n])
  } else if (m[n] >= 0.4 & m[n] <= 0.5){
    print(m[n])
    break
  }
  n = n + 1
}

# (c) repeat loop
n = 0
m = runif(20)
repeat{
  if(n < 20)
    n <- n + 1
  else
    break
  if (m[n] > 0.1 & m[n] <= 0.2){
    next
  } else if (m[n] < 0.3 | m[n] > 0.8){
    print(m[n])
  } else if (m[n] >= 0.4 & m[n] <= 0.5){
    print(m[n])
    break
  }
}
```

As a final note, whenever pseudo-random number generators are used you should set the initial value in order for the results to be reproducible. This is done like this:

```
set.seed(6019)  # or any other value, 6019 is the seed
```

This is put *before* the first call to `runif`.

Comment: Thank you Rui, I was doing the repeat loop on my own and how come u set n = 0?

Comment: @Renee Because in this case it increments `n` right at the top of the loop. This is because unlike `while`, `repeat` doesn't finish on a condition, so the condition must be checked first.